# React native android emulator network

Tags: android, react-native, axios

I used to run my emulator and have react native debugger to debug my apps.
My app has some promises for http requests with AXIOS.

Suddenly since two days now my emulator does not handle those requests. When you press e.g login it show that is trying to do the connection and it times out after some minutes.

If i enable "network inspect" on the debugger is working. But some WebSockets that i have could not connect to the server.

If i plug real device it is working fine without the debugger.

I tried wiping the emulator and i tried a different one but nothing.

Does anyone has any clue?